# silverlight object border

Tags: html, silverlight

EDIT: I need to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.  I am popping up a ChildWindow from the application.  When the childwindow is displayed and the browser is resized, there are no scrollbars and there is no way to reach parts of the childwindow.  The scrollViewer.scrollViewerVisibility=auto suggestion below displays scrollbars but they belong to the main application for which all the controls are disabled when a ChildWindow is displayed.

I'm trying to get the browser to display scrollbars when it is resized smaller than my SL application.  I've acheived this by setting width and height for the object tag in the html.  The problem is, now a black 1px border appears around the application.  I've tried various attributes and styles on the tag and containing tag but cannot get it to disappear.  Any ideas?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="1230" height="830" style="border-style:none">
          <param name="source" value="Silverlight.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Where? Style for the object tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="overflow:auto !Important;visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
```

Comment: To remove border, add frameborder="0" in iframe tag: <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: The border isn't on the iframe, it's on the object.

Comment: apologies, missed that point. look in your Applcation_Startup event handler, is there any scrollviewer control that is displaying the border?  because you are already setting border style to be none in the object tag.  Also add this to your object tag: style="border-style: none" width="100%" height="100%">

Comment: The whole point of this is that I'm trying to give my object a static height and width, which enables the scroll bars.  The width="100%" height="100%" solves the problem but I get no scrollbars.

Comment: look in your main xaml page, for the main parent control i.e. stackpanel, add ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" For vertical scrollbar.